# How to grant Nagios permissions to run some commands in custom script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, nagios

I have been making some custom shell scripts for my nagios machine. I was able to make them run just fine but for some reason some commands in the script don't seem to be working.

For instance commands like echo, cut , ps , grep work fine but commands like touch, useradd dont seem to work, even with sudo. If I run the script from the terminal, all the commands in the script work.

How can I give nagios permissions to run these commands?

I'm running nagios3 on ubuntu 14.04.5 lts

Edit: Added a few lines of code which aren't being run

```
sudo useradd -m $USERNAME
(echo $PASSWORD; echo $PASSWORD) | sudo smbpasswd -s -a $USERNAME
```

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Did you add the nagios user to /etc/sudoers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way is setup permission for Nagios user on monitored server, for instance NRPE, in `/etc/sudoers` file.

**1. method**

Try add something like this in your sudoers file.

```
Defaults:nrpe   !requiretty
nrpe  ALL= NOPASSWD: useradd -m
nrpe  ALL= NOPASSWD: smbpasswd -s -a
```

PS: For easy editing sudoers file you can use `visudo` command ;-)

**2. method**

Or you can try add Nagios user to `sudo` group via `sudo usermod -aG sudo <username>`

`-a` stands for add

`G` is for group

Comment: It seems it was both answers, add NOPASSWD to sudoers file and sudo in cfg file

Answer (score 1):

Tell nagios to run the script as sudo in your .cfg file...

Assuming its permissions problem.

Comment: Have tried that already, I get a status information: (null) with a warning. If I run the command_line in the .cfg file from the terminal it works fine.

Comment: Its because you're running that from root, try su - nagios then running it see what it tells you... If its a permission issue then you need to add sudo appropriately.

Comment: Please add the permitons of you script as well as the check+config if you're still having trouble... But the issue is almost certainly sudo...

Comment: not sure if understood correctly but my scripts permissions are 777 and my .cfg file for the script is just: command_name   samba1 and the command_line     /home/asist/lapr5/samba1.sh

Comment: Is the owner and group of this file nagios:nagios ? 
If not make sure it is 
    chown nagios:nagios  /home/asist/lapr5/samba1.sh

Comment: Open the script up in vim and post the contents into your question so we can test and advise...

Comment: changed the owner and group to nagios. But it shouldn't matter ? All other core plugins are owned by root and seem to work fine, my plugin also had 777 permissions. Anyway I moved it to the default plugin directory and also didnt work. Added the problematic commands as requested

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** `/etc/sudoers` f**ile using visudo**, this allows automatic file check for errors.

```
Defaults:nrpe !requiretty
nrpe ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/command/or/script
```

**Verify sudo has assigned the above permissions to the user in this case** nrpe

```
sudo -U nrpe -l
```

you should see the command you added listed within the outpul

Edit `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`
**Add your command to the end of the file**

e.g.
command[your_command]=/usr/bin/sudo /path/to/your/command/or/script

**Restart nrpe**
Centos: `systemctl restart nrpe` (use the command available based on your Operating system)